# Error / Exception Handling with empty files in R

Tags: r, exception, error-handling, try-catch

I heard about exception handling first time in python two days ago and consequently I want to apply here in R. I had a look at a number of questions post either here in stack overflow or some other online Q&As but I am still really confused in using it.

I would really appreciate if someone can answer it with this simple example so later on I can apply it to my questions.

For example I have 3 data files with file names shown below; and the **first file is a 0 bytes empty file**. What I can do to continue run the loop for all files and the number extracted from the empty file can be expressed as NA?

```
    > output_names_hdf5_list[1:5]
    [1] "simulation-results fL=0.1,fks=1,fno=0.1,fnc=0.1,fr=0.1,fs=0.1.hdf5"  
    [2] "simulation-results fL=0.1,fks=1,fno=0.1,fnc=0.1,fr=0.1,fs=1.05.hdf5" 
    [3] "simulation-results fL=0.1,fks=1,fno=0.1,fnc=0.1,fr=0.1,fs=2.hdf5"    

    for (i in 1:5){
        channelflow_outlet[,i]=h5read(paste(outputdir, output_names_hdf5_list[i], sep=""),"Channel")$Qc_out[460,][2:100]
    }
```

With `try` function I can manage to run the program without stuck in an error message but when I replace the argunment with `channelflow_outlet[,i]= h5read(....)` inside `try` function, it just returns error.

```
    for (i in 1:5){
        try(h5read(paste(outputdir, output_names_hdf5_list[i], sep=""),"Channel")$Qc_out[460,][2:100])
    }
```

Without error handling, it will have a error message like this.

```
    > h5read(paste(outputdir, output_names_hdf5_list[1], sep=""),"Channel")$Qc_out[460,][2:100]
    HDF5: unable to open file
    Error in h5checktypeOrOpenLoc(file, readonly = TRUE) : 
      Error in h5checktypeOrOpenLoc(). File 'D:/Data/Mleonard/pytopkapi.staged.makefile/RunModel/Output/3x6-729-04072014/simulation-results fL=0.1,fks=1,fno=0.1,fnc=0.1,fr=0.1,fs=0.1.hdf5' is not a valid HDF5 file.
    >
```

Comment: See examples in `?tryCatch`. You can specify behavior on error or warning on the fly.

Comment: @ Roman, I have tried with `tryCatch()` and rewrite the `h5read()` reading file part to be a function, but it still doesn't work. The results all returns with NA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope my code helps. For those messages in the code, you can delete them if you want. They are here purely to help you see where it shows warning or error.

```
   setwd("D:/Dropbox/Test/"); outputdir = "D:/Dropbox/Test/"

   output_names_hdf5_list=c("simulation-results fL=0.1,fks=1,fno=1.05,fnc=1.05,fr=1.05,fs=1.05.hdf5",
             "simulation-results fL=0.1,fks=1,fno=1.05,fnc=2,fr=1.05,fs=1.05.hdf5",
             "simulation-results fL=0.1,fks=1,fno=2,fnc=1.05,fr=0.1,fs=1.05.hdf5",
             "simulation-results fL=0.1,fks=1,fno=2,fnc=1.05,fr=2,fs=2.hdf5",
             "simulation-results fL=0.5,fks=1,fno=2,fnc=2,fr=0.1,fs=1.05.hdf5")

   channelflow_outlet = matrix(NA, nrow=100, ncol=5)

   hdf5_list_reading_tool= function(output_names_hdf5_list) {
    out = tryCatch(
       { 
            message("This is the 'try' part")
            h5read(paste(outputdir, output_names_hdf5_list, sep=""),"Channel")$Qc_out[460,][2:100]
       },
       error=function(cond) {
            message("Here's the original error message:")
            message(cond)
            return(rep(NA,100))
       },
       warning=function(cond) {
            message("Here's the original warning message:")
            message(cond)
            return(rep(NA,100))
       },
       finally={
            message(paste("Processed URL:", output_names_hdf5_list))
            message("Some other message at the end")
       }
    )
    return(out)
    }

    channelflow_outlet=sapply(output_names_hdf5_list, hdf5_list_reading_tool)
```